# Reduce the width of ribbon without changing the position so it fits the box

Tags: html, css

I would like to reduce the `width` of the ribbon so it fits without changing the position of the ribbon.

Can someone guide me as to where I'm going wrong?

```css
.ribbon-content {
  position: relative;
}

.ribbon-content>[class*=ribbon] {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2000;
  line-height: 2em;
  display: block;
  width: 10em;
  height: 2.5em;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}

.ribbon-content>[class*=ribbon]::before,
.ribbon-content>[class*=ribbon]::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  inset: 0;
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(2em 0, 8em 0, 10em 2em, 10em 2.5em, 9.5em 2em, 0.5em 2em, 0 2.5em, 0 2em);
  clip-path: polygon(2em 0, 8em 0, 10em 2em, 10em 2.5em, 9.5em 2em, 0.5em 2em, 0 2.5em, 0 2em);
}

.ribbon-content>[class*=ribbon]::before {
  top: 0.1em;
  height: 1.8em;
  border: 1px dotted rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  border-left: none;
  border-right: none;
}

.ribbon-content>[class*=ribbon]::after {
  z-index: -1;
  background-color: #ff6347;
  border-bottom: 0.5em solid #505050;
  transition: background-color 0.2s ease-in-out;
}

.ribbon-content>.ribbon-top-left {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  transform: translate(-3.85em, 1.4em) rotate(-45deg);
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 0.65rem;
}

.box {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 20em;
  min-height: 10em;
  margin: 2em;
  background-color: #333;
}
```

```html
<div class="box ribbon-content"><span class="ribbon-top-left" href="#">NEW</span></div>
```

Comment: Perhaps clarify what is meant by "it fits the box" since just looking at it it seems you just can move it to "fit"

Comment: I want the width to decrease. So moving the ribbon won't work as it would keep the width of the ribbon the same width.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is kind of a two part answer.  The second builds on the first.

You want a block to change span to div and remove the `display:block` since that is the difference there.

Move the ribbon to "wrap around" better
`top: 0.75em; left: 0.5em;`

Remove the box `position: relative;` and the ribbon `position: absolute;` as not needed.

Then, set up the box as a border box with no margin or padding:

```
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      box-sizing: border-box;
      font-size: 16px;
    }
```

Font size not strictly needed here but since all modern browsers default to that but this makes it specific.

Set the margin on the ribbon `margin-left: 1.5em;` so it moves to "wrap" the box visually.

Remove the `/*  top: 0.1em; height: 1.8em;*/` as not needed.

```css
.ribbon-content {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-size: 16px;
}

.ribbon-content>[class*=ribbon] {
  margin-left: 1.5em;
  z-index: 2000;
  line-height: 2em;
  width: 10em;
  height: 2.5em;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}

.ribbon-content>[class*=ribbon]::before,
.ribbon-content>[class*=ribbon]::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  inset: 0;
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(2em 0, 8em 0, 10em 2em, 10em 2.5em, 9.5em 2em, 0.5em 2em, 0 2.5em, 0 2em);
  clip-path: polygon(2em 0, 8em 0, 10em 2em, 10em 2.5em, 9.5em 2em, 0.5em 2em, 0 2.5em, 0 2em);
}

.ribbon-content>[class*=ribbon]::before {
  /*  top: 0.1em;
  height: 1.8em;*/
  border: 1px dotted rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  border-left: none;
  border-right: none;
}

.ribbon-content>[class*=ribbon]::after {
  z-index: -1;
  background-color: #ff6347;
  border-bottom: 0.5em solid #505050;
  transition: background-color 0.2s ease-in-out;
}

.ribbon-content>.ribbon-top-left {
  top: 0.75em;
  left: 0.5em;
  transform: translate(-3.85em, 1.4em) rotate(-45deg);
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 0.65rem;
}

.box {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 20em;
  min-height: 10em;
  /* margin: 2em; can be anything since this is BOTH elements contained */
  background-color: #333;
}
```

```html
<div class="box ribbon-content">
  <div class="ribbon-top-left" href="#">NEW</div>
</div>
```

Now with all the above just adjust the ribbon font size as needed perhaps:

Still not 100% sure on the intent here but you can also wrap the text and re-size that while adjusting the ribbon height and left margin re:

```
.ribbon-content>.ribbon-top-left {
  font-size: 0.5rem;
  top: 0.75em;
  left: 0.5em;
  transform: translate(-3.85em, 1.4em) rotate(-45deg);
  color: #fff;
}
```

```css
.ribbon-content {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-size: 16px;
}

.ribbon-content>[class*=ribbon] {
  margin-left: 1.75em;
  z-index: 2000;
  width: 10em;
  height: 3em;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}

.ribbon-content>[class*=ribbon]::before,
.ribbon-content>[class*=ribbon]::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  inset: 0;
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(2em 0, 8em 0, 10em 2em, 10em 2em, 9.5em 2em, 0.5em 2em, 0 2.5em, 0 2em);
  clip-path: polygon(2em 0, 8em 0, 10em 2em, 10em 2.5em, 9.5em 2em, 0.5em 2em, 0 2.5em, 0 2em);
}

.ribbon-content>[class*=ribbon]::before {
  border: 1px dotted rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  border-left: none;
  border-right: none;
}

.ribbon-content>[class*=ribbon]::after {
  z-index: -1;
  background-color: #ff6347;
  border-bottom: 0.5em solid #505050;
  transition: background-color 0.2s ease-in-out;
}

.ribbon-content>.ribbon-top-left {
  font-size: 0.5rem;
  top: 0.75em;
  left: 0.5em;
  transform: translate(-3.85em, 1.4em) rotate(-45deg);
  color: #fff;
}

.ribbon-content>.ribbon-top-left .just-text {
  font-size: 1.5em;
  height: 2.5em;
}

.box {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 20em;
  min-height: 10em;
  /* margin: 2em; can be anything since this is BOTH elements contained */
  background-color: #333;
}
```

```html
<div class="box ribbon-content">
  <div class="ribbon-top-left" href="#"><span class="just-text">NEW</span></div>
</div>
```

Comment: You have simply reduced the font size which is not what I want. I want to keep the height of the ribbon and the font size but reduce the width.

Comment: I think YOU know what you mean by "reduce the width" but that is unclear.  IF for example you "reduce the width" visually but not the height, the angle would change from what is approx. 45 degree to something else - is THAT what you want?

Comment: OR do you mean reduce both the width and height but not the text font size thus effectively moving it up and to the left IF it tightly wraps the left and top as the top does currently (in your example)?

Comment: Yes but the height can be kept as-is or slightly reduce. Thank you.

Comment: I adjusted the height and the left margin and wrapped the text so it might be larger but if this does not get what you are after then I have no idea on your actual goal since I had A or B comments and you said "Yes" which did nothing to clarify IMHO.

Answer (score 1):

The width, the `tramsform` property and the parameter for `clip-path` are all related to the width so I'd use [CSS custom properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_custom_properties) and [calc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc) to ensure they scale.

I've done the `clip-path` for you but you'll have to sort out the translate yourself. You might need to do a bit of geometry to figure this out.  Code below:

```css
.ribbon-content {
  position: relative;
  --width: 5em;
}

.ribbon-content>[class*=ribbon] {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2000;
  line-height: 2em;
  display: block;
  width: var(--width);
  height: 2.5em;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}

.ribbon-content>[class*=ribbon]::before,
.ribbon-content>[class*=ribbon]::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  inset: 0;
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(
    calc(var(--width) * 0.2) 0,
    calc(var(--width) * 0.8) 0,
    calc(var(--width)) 2em, 
    calc(var(--width)) 2.5em, 
    calc(var(--width) * 0.95) 2em, 
    calc(var(--width) * 0.05) 2em, 
    0 2.5em, 
    0 2em);
  clip-path: polygon(
    calc(var(--width) * 0.2) 0, 
    calc(var(--width) * 0.8) 0, 
    calc(var(--width)) 2em, 
    calc(var(--width)) 2.5em, 
    calc(var(--width) * 0.95) 2em, 
    calc(var(--width) * 0.05) 2em, 
    0 2.5em, 
    0 2em);
}

.ribbon-content>[class*=ribbon]::before {
  top: 0.1em;
  height: 1.8em;
  border: 1px dotted rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  border-left: none;
  border-right: none;
}

.ribbon-content>[class*=ribbon]::after {
  z-index: -1;
  background-color: #ff6347;
  border-bottom: 0.5em solid #505050;
}

.ribbon-content>.ribbon-top-left {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  /* you'd need to do a bit of geometry to make this work consistently */
  transform: translate(calc(var(--width) * -0.3), 0) rotate(-45deg);
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 0.65rem;
}

.box {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 20em;
  min-height: 10em;
  margin: 2em;
  background-color: #333;
}
```

```html
<div class="box ribbon-content"><span class="ribbon-top-left" href="#">NEW</span></div>
```

Comment: Thank you but the shape is all damaged! I tried to change back the shape of the ribbon but without success. Thank you for the effort though.

Comment: Are you wanting just the width to change or are you wanting to scale the height with it too?

Comment: Just the width but may be about 10% decrease in height may help.